# What is the best practice for Wakanda to 4D error handling?

Tags: wakanda, 4d-database

In 4D Mobile architecture, what is the best practice for ensuring that Wakanda interactions with 4D do not error resulting in thread failure.

There can be many such interactions: query, entity reference col[0], .save, method calls, etc...

We want to trap all these errors and return our own message, rather than have the thread fail due to a Wakanda<->4D interaction failure.

Invoking an on-err-call function for all of these types of interactions would eliminate wrapping all calls in a try/catch statement.

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge, there is no such error handling strategy between 4D and Wakanda. We also experience request drops and have to code our own protective measures. I hope I am wrong and another answer makes mine irrelevant.

Comment: This is our experience over the last ~12 months as well

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck asking about this on the premium forums back when they still existed. I wish I had a better answer.